# How to compare version numeric string in the format of x.x.x.x

Tags: c#, string, compare

How can I compare version string in the format of x.x.x.x

e.g. compare `3.0.1750` to `3.0.1749`

meaning

```
if (3.0.1750 > 3.0.1749)
{
   // do this
}
```

Comment: A minimum of research would have given you the answer. First hit on google for "c# version compare".

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Version` class to compare between versions:

```
var v1 = new Version("3.0.1750");
var v2 = new Version("3.0.1749");

bool isV1Greater = v1 > v2; // true
bool isV2Greater = v1 < v2; // false
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use class [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) to achieve that. Here is a sample of how to use it from MSDN:

```
Version v1 = new Version(2, 0);
Version v2 = new Version("2.1");
Console.Write("Version {0} is ", v1);
switch(v1.CompareTo(v2))
{
   case 0:
      Console.Write("the same as");
      break;
   case 1:
      Console.Write("later than");
      break;
   case -1:
      Console.Write("earlier than");
      break;
}
Console.WriteLine(" Version {0}.", v2);
```